# Web links not functioning on mobile display

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-modal

I have developed my portfolio website using a sample grid-based bootstrap template.
After coding, I have tried testing the hyperlinks on the mobile device. But the links does not function on the mobile display.

I attempted some suggested solutions found online. But no luck so far. Can anybody help me find the issue? Please.

Portfolio link: https://pruthvirajn.github.io/

Page with problem: Contact page (right-top menu option in the home page)

Links not functioning: twitter button, google+ button and rest of the hyperlinks in the portfolio.

Comment: please provide your codes,else we are helpess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see below, `col-lg-12 text-center` is covering the links, so when you try to click the link, you are actually clicking the container for the `h2.project-title`.

To fix this, add this CSS:

```
.contact col-lg-12.text-center {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This allows the user to click through the container and on the links. [More info on pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

or:

```
.contact col-lg-12.text-center {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This makes the container only as tall as the title, allowing you to click the things.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for such a descriptive solution and quick response!
I was easily able to achieve the fix using the second suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap so you can use a class to centralize its link by adding a class, hope it will work `<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/PruthvirajNGS" class="btn-social btn-outline text-center"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-twitter"></i></a>`

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! I believe even this solution would fix my issue.